How to mock with Spock
I want to mock with Spock a method getEntity for the Spring ResTemplate
Product getProducts(ProductSearch request) {
  Map<String, Object> queryParam = new HashMap<>();
  queryParam.put("id", request.getProductId());
  queryParam.put("category", request.getCategory());

  UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
  queryParam.forEach(uriComponentsBuilder::queryParam);

  String url = uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString();
  return restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Product.class).getBody();
}

The problem I face is how to I mock the getBody() part . I tried this and got a NullPointerException
class ProductClientSpec extends Specification {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock()
  ProductClient legacyOpenSlotsClient = new ProductClient(restTemplate)

  def setup() {}

  def 'should return product'() {
    given:
    ProductSearch request = createProductRequest()
    Product product = createProductResponse()

    when:
    ProductClient.getProducts(request)

    then:
    1 * restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/products", Product.class).getBody() >> product
  }
}


The problem could be in the part of the code that is invisible here. Therefore, a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to reproduce the problem instead of just class fragments would be helpful. If I can reproduce the problem, it is likely that I can also answer your question. Please do not expect anyone to guess what the rest of the code might look like and add it by themselves. Without a stack trace, I also do not know where your NPE comes from.

How do I produce this? restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Product.class).getBody(); in the real method call. This api is one I don't have any control over. the test code fails here     1 * restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/products", Product.class).getBody() >> product

If I remove the getBody() chained method the null pointer goes away. The problem is I want to extract the body i.e. Product and not have to unwrap in the classes that use the ProductClient

Thank you for your response. I followed you advice and got it working. Cheers again

Adding some line breaks to avoid having to scroll horizontally and to reveal the main problem:
then:
  1 * restTemplate
    .getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/products", Product.class)
    .getBody()
  >> product

Chained method calls are invalid syntax for mocking. The second method call is on the ResponseEntity returned by the first, but that one you did not mock.
Lacking an MCVE to try this on, the next bit of code is just an untested sketch to show how this could be done in principle:
RestTemplate restTemplate = Mock()
ResponseEntity responseEntity = Mock()
// ...

then:
  1 * restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/products", Product.class) >> responseEntity 
  1 * responseEntity.getBody() >> product



I do not understand this part of your comment - The second method call is on the ResponseEntity returned by the first, but that one you did not mock. Can you please explain?  Should the first be ; 1 * restTemplate
.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/products", Product.class) >> reponseEntity ?

Before, you said: "I followed you advice and got it working." That is why I did not elaborate more in my answer. And now, suddenly you do not understand it anymore? I am quite surprised. Besides, there istill is no MCVE from your side, which I could just modify and explain using it as a reproducer.

I did get it working but not using the RestTemplate method getforEntity. I used getForObject instead which gives the result directly. However, I am interested in understanding whether getForEnity.getBody() could work and if so, how?

I mean something like in the updated answer.

Thank you very much. I see it now, makes perfect sense. Really appreciated!
